# Inconsistent translation on a WP site

Tags: themes, homepage, translation, language

I have a WP site that I installed with the French translation, as provided by Wordpress France, and which is quite accurate. I wanted to apply an English-only theme, which is not using the PO files, but rather has all text hard-coded in the PHP code. I translated all files, but I noticed that when I display the home page, some of the words remain in English, but whenever I display something other than the home page, those are all in French. Is there something either in Wordpress or the theme files that actually make a distinction between the home page and others to display different pieces of text ?

Answer (score 1):

When every message is hard coded in the theme files there can be no problem with [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) anymore. So, yes, depending on the theme WordPress can [use different templates for home and other pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). But no, this has nothing to do with automatic translations. You have simply forgot to translate some strings, possibly in `front-page.php` or `home.php`.